# ui-router/angular-hybrid - route not recognized on initial load/reload

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-hybrid

It seems that routes that are registered within ng2+ module using the `@ui-router/angular-hybrid` are not recognized on initial load/reload. The same route is working if e.g. navigated by typing the url.

I've followed the official upgrade docs from [@ui-router/angular-hybrid](https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid/blob/master/README.md)

Here is the ng2+ `AppModule` code:

```
const states: NgHybridStateDeclaration[] = [
  {
    name: 'x',
    url: '/x',
    component: XComponent
  }
];

enableProdMode();

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    UIRouterUpgradeModule.forRoot({states: states}),
    ComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  exports: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class Ng2AppModule {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UpgradeModule)) private upgrade: UpgradeModule,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => Config)) private config: Config
  ) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document as any, ['app'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}
```

And the bootstrapping logic:

```
AppModule.config([
  '$urlServiceProvider',
  ($urlService: UrlService) => $urlService.deferIntercept()
]);

getConfig()
  .then((config: Config) => {
    console.log('CONFIG::::', config);
    AppModule.constant('config', config);

    setAngularLib(angular);

    platformBrowserDynamic([
      {
        provide: Config,
        useValue: config
      }
    ])
      .bootstrapModule(Ng2AppModule)
      .then(platformRef => {
        platformRef.injector.get<NgZone>(NgZone).run(() => {
          const urlService = platformRef.injector.get(UIRouter).urlService;

          urlService.listen();
          urlService.sync();
        });

        downgradeSharedComponents(AppModule);
      });
  })
```

P.S. Existing angularjs routes are working properly, the problem is with routes registered within the ng2+ module.

Any help is appreciated, thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure this out on my own and wanted to post the answer in case anyone encounter similar issue. 
Turned out we had a weird logic in our old angularjs code that was deferring `$urlRouter` url synchronization:

```
$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
...
$urlRouter.sync();
```

Once removed, issue described above disappeared.